# Intercepting Actions in React Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React application that uses Redux.

The application displays the results of some calculations at the top and some of the constituents that go into those calculations at the bottom. The user can click a button which pops up a modal in which the user can add one of these constituents. This will fire off an action during which it will send that new constituent to the backend, which will make those calculations have different results.

As you might expect, what I want is to refresh those results from the server based on the new data. The calculations are quite complex so replicating the calculation in the UI is not an option.

There is a `loadConstituents()` method which is called by `componentWillMount()` when the user lands on the page. I basically need to call this method again once the server confirms to the user that the data was received (via a `SAVE_SUCCESS` action).

**How can I intercept an action in my component?**

Alternatively, is there a better pattern for achieving this?

The best thing I could think of is passing the `loadConstituents()` function to the modal, which would pass it to the call, which will execute it once the call is done but passing a function through so many classes as a parameter seems very hacky.

Comment: you may need a middleware like redux-saga

Comment: Note: agree with @oosniss you'll need a middleware (thunk, saga etc.)
Also, make the async calls in [componentDidMount()](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/). Let me know if you need help with thunk.

Comment: If you want to use redux-thunk like the other two commented. Here is a good answer to look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35073808/10301134

Comment: Use thunk. Just add with `npm i --save redux-thunk` and apply it as a middleware that will 'intercept' your actions when you dispatch then

Comment: @Dupocas npm saves automatically now btw

Comment: Don't know why people are not using saga. It is far more powerful than thunk

Comment: out of habit xD

Comment: Don't know why people are not driving tanks. They are far more powerful than cars.